# GroupBy results from a HasManyThrough a ManyToMany relationship in Laravel 5.5

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, laravel-5.5

I have a complex relationship like a ManyToMany relationship between `Category` and `Products` and a `Product` can have many `Inventory` listings from different Shops(user). A `Shop` can have multiple listing of the same `Product` as a variant(color/size).

Everything is fine till now!

The issue begins when showing the listing to the visitors. I want to show all listings under a category but don't want to show multiple listings of the same product from the same shop. Instead, want to pick the lowest `sale_price` listing from the shop.

I have three models and relations are like:

```
     class Category extends Model
     {
         public function products()
         {
             return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
         }
     }


     class Product extends Model
     {

        public function categories()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
        }

        public function inventories()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Inventory::class);
        }
    } 


    class Inventory extends Model
    {
        public function product()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
        }

    }
```

Tables:

```
    //Categories
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
    });


    //Products
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
    });

    //Pivot table
    Schema::create('category_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('category_id');
        $table->integer('product_id');
    });


    //Inventories
    Schema::create('inventories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('shop_id');
        $table->integer('product_id');
        $table->string('sku', 200);
        $table->string('title');
        $table->decimal('sale_price', 10, 2);
    });
```

As Laravel doesn't provide any `manyToManyThough()` relationship. I have added a `listings` method in the `Category` model. This method returns all listings:

```
public function listings()
{
    $product_ids = $this->products()->pluck('products.id')->all();

    return Inventory::whereIn('product_id', $product_ids)->paginate(20);
}
```

Then I tried this:

```
public function listings()
{
    $product_ids = $this->products()->pluck('products.id')->all();

    return Inventory::whereIn('product_id', $product_ids)->groupBy('shop_id','product_id')->paginate(20);
}
```

These methods produce MySQL GroupBy Error. Yes, I can filter the result after taking all result but that'll affect the pagination. How to get the sorted results and also keep the pagination ability. Thanks and day by day I got more indebted to the community. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a direct relationship by "skipping" the `products` table:

```php
public function listings() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Inventory::class,
        'category_product',
        null,
        'product_id',
        null,
        'product_id'
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's really helped. Any idea how can I get the result as I want?

Comment: Did you try something like `$category->groupBy('shop_id','product_id')->paginate(20);`? Can you add some sample data and the expected result to your question?